installing android in qemu
Considering the next link:
How to virtualize Android with QEMU/KVM
In the link description is written:

As you may have noticed in the command, VNC will only listen locally and is recommended for security. The traffic will not be encrypted and there is no access control and it is not safe to publish it to the internet. Therefore, to access via VNC you can tunnel through OpenSSH. Open another SSH connection to the Ubuntu server and forward the VNC port:

Is there any way to install android in qemu, and in the same time, to be safe to connect that guest android client to the internet?
